# Can you convert a XAML DrawingImage back into an SVG for editting?

Tags: c#, xaml, svg

A design company made an application design in WPF 2 years ago, and now we're looking at changing the text on one of the images. No SVG files were provided, only the XAML code used, and the developer who worked on the project at the design company no longer works there. I know he used Expression Blend for the design.

Any help with **possible ways to convert XAML like this to SVG** would help, or even suggestions on **what tools were used to generate this XAML.** I saw [this topic on converting XAML to SVG,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764/xaml-to-svg) but it looked like the tools only did conversions with SVGs originally converted in their tool.

A resource dictionary contains all the DrawingImage objects used to display images through the application. Here is one of the images we're looking at editting:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="MotorControlBackground">
<DrawingImage.Drawing>
  <DrawingGroup>
    <DrawingGroup.Children>
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF466280" Geometry="F1 M -1138.47,3547.06C -1128.45,3557.08 -1112.14,3557.17 -1102.23,3547.25L -1024.29,3469.32L -1118.83,3374.78L -1214.79,3470.74L -1138.47,3547.06 Z ">
        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
          <Pen Thickness="2.5" MiterLimit="2.75" Brush="#FF212121"/>
        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
      </GeometryDrawing>
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1 M -1131.22,3533.84L -1138.68,3533.84L -1138.68,3532.34L -1135.91,3532.34L -1135.91,3521.89L -1138.68,3521.89L -1138.68,3520.4C -1137.64,3520.4 -1136.87,3520.25 -1136.38,3519.95C -1135.88,3519.65 -1135.6,3519.09 -1135.54,3518.26L -1133.99,3518.26L -1133.99,3532.34L -1131.22,3532.34L -1131.22,3533.84 Z "/>
      <!-- ... Heavily shortened. Expect around 100 more lines here ... -->
      <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M -1175.94,3268.96L -1057.64,3475.82">
        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
          <Pen Thickness="1.33333" MiterLimit="2.75" Brush="#88C7C7C7"/>
        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
      </GeometryDrawing>
      <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M -1086.99,3255.92L -1147.5,3485.59">
        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
          <Pen Thickness="1.33333" MiterLimit="2.75" Brush="#88C7C7C7"/>
        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
      </GeometryDrawing>
      <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF0C407C" Geometry="F1 M -1025.41,3324.46C -1035.45,3304.48 -1051.7,3288.14 -1071.58,3278.06C -1085.54,3270.98 -1101.28,3266.99 -1117.91,3266.99C -1131.79,3266.99 -1145.06,3269.78 -1157.2,3274.82C -1182.66,3285.41 -1203.09,3305.94 -1213.63,3331.52C -1218.64,3343.71 -1221.42,3357.05 -1221.42,3371C -1221.42,3385.48 -1218.44,3399.29 -1213.06,3411.83C -1202.56,3436.34 -1182.94,3456.06 -1158.55,3466.61C -1146.05,3472.01 -1132.31,3475.02 -1117.91,3475.02C -1103.67,3475.02 -1090.09,3472.09 -1077.72,3466.81C -1052.97,3456.24 -1033.07,3436.25 -1022.56,3411.38C -1017.3,3398.95 -1014.39,3385.3 -1014.39,3371C -1014.39,3354.3 -1018.37,3338.48 -1025.41,3324.46 Z "/>
      <!-- ... shortened some more ... -->
      <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M -1021.98,3324.73C -1021.98,3355.74 -1069.88,3368.43 -1117.29,3372.09C -1117.75,3372.13 -1120.57,3372.05 -1120.57,3372.05C -1167.81,3368.32 -1215.32,3355.62 -1215.32,3324.73C -1215.32,3286.57 -1170.4,3255.35 -1115.48,3255.35L -1121.82,3255.35C -1066.92,3255.35 -1021.98,3286.57 -1021.98,3324.73 Z ">
        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.548505,0.143509" EndPoint="0.548505,0.805904">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
              <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
      </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingGroup.Children>
  </DrawingGroup>
</DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inkscape (an SVG editor) has limited support for XAML.

Last time I tried it, the XAML support wasn't perfect, but that was maybe 6 months ago. It may have improved since then.

Comment: Although it didn't solve my problem in the end, I accepted the answer based on the fact that I didn't realize Inkscape had the XAML support, and I could likely figure out Inkscape's formatting, copy-paste the Paths from my own XAML, and reopen. I learned that the code above was generated through creating an image in Illustrator, importing that to Micrsoft Design, and importing that into Microsoft Blend.

Comment: What program is meant by Microsoft Design? http://www.microsoft.com/en/us/sitemap.aspx#Products reveals that the category "Design & user experience" contains only Expression and Silverlight.

Comment: I found the solution. It is called Microsoft Expression Design 4 and is installed when installing Microsoft Expression Studio 4 Ultimate.

Comment: Using command line: `& 'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe'  -z input.xaml  -l output.svg`

Answer (score -2):

It may be a solution to convert XAML to PNG by means of http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422523/Convert-XAML-Vector-Graphic-to-PNG and then converting PNG to SVG. There are more options between PNG and SVG in terms of conversion. I have converted my XAML drawings into EMF with this approach.

Comment: Xaml and SVG are vector formats while png is a pixel format, so there is no point in going from png to svg...

Comment: @Peter it could be relevant to lots of people if they have a tool that doesn't support SVG. It's trivial to go from vector to pixels, just not at all the other way around.

Comment: @Chazt3n when going from vector to pixel you loose data a lot of it, so to go from Vector -> Pixel -> Vector is a bad idea, if possible skip the pixel step otherwise you can be 99.9% sure its not the same vector image anymore...

Comment: @Peter it is obvious that you lose data, and cannot get the same when you do such conversions. I needed to have SVG to use in mobile development because XAML is not supported of course. However I had a very large XAML icon library. After converting XAML into bitmap and then into SVG worked fine for simple icons, lost data was absolutely acceptable.